# Date returned from Gallery always returns January 1 1970

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am trying to build a gallery app.I have fetched image path and date added from `MediaStore.Images`.

I have used the following code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getAllShownImagesPath(Activity activity) {
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;
        int column_index_date;
        ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<String>();
        String absolutePathOfImage = null;
        long dateofimage;
        uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA,MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME };

        cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        column_index_date=cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED);
        column_index_folder_name = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            System.out.println("Imagepath-->"+absolutePathOfImage);

            dateofimage = cursor.getLong(column_index_date);
            System.out.println("date--->"+dateofimage);


            Date d = new Date(dateofimage); 
            java.text.DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy h:mmaa"); 
            String dateString = formatter.format(d);

            //String  dateString= convertDate(dateofimage,"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

            System.out.println("date in format--->"+dateString);
            listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
        }
        return listOfAllImages;
    }
```

Please see the logcat I have posted below.The image path is coming perfectly,so as the time in milliseconds.But when I try to convert that millisecond into Date format,then I always get:**January 17, 1970**

```
09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 8:49PM
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/ModFace/Modface727142626.jpg
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date--->1437988950
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 8:56PM
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/ModFace/Modface727142639.jpg
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date--->1437988950
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 8:56PM
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/data/data/images/SILogo2015.png
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date--->1438252547
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 9:00PM
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/Download/ebook.png
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date--->1438668694
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 9:07PM
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20150811_153514.jpg
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date--->1439287514
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 9:18PM
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/mainstreamtemp.jpg
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date--->1439800096
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 9:26PM
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/mainstream2.jpg
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date--->1439800096
    09-16 11:10:53.994: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 9:26PM
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 10:01PM
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/shiatoolkitimages/mashlool07.gif
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): date--->1441888058
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 10:01PM
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/shiatoolkitimages/mashlool08.gif
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): date--->1441888058
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 10:01PM
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/shiatoolkitimages/mashlool09.gif
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): date--->1441888058
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/shiatoolkitimages/mashlool10.gif
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): date--->1441888058
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/shiatoolkitimages/mashlool11.gif
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 10:01PM
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): Imagepath-->/storage/emulated/0/siat_hadith.png
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): date--->1442042302
    09-16 11:10:54.024: I/System.out(10098): date in format--->January 17, 1970 10:04PM
```

I have also tried another method to convert millis in date,but ended up getting the same result:

```
public static String convertDate(long dateInMilliseconds,String dateFormat) {
        return DateFormat.format(dateFormat, dateInMilliseconds).toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number you are getting from your cursor is in the format of [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which counts the number of seconds elapsed since 1 January 1970. For your date creation you want value in milliseconds. The easy solution is to multiply your result by 1000 and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I will try it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this

```
         Date d = new Date(dateofimage); 
        java.text.DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy h:mmaa"); 
        String dateString = formatter.format(d);
```

try this

```
        Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(dateofimage * 1000);
        String dateString = timeStamp.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I will try this.

Comment: toLocaleString();   is depreceted